# Python Exchange ActiveSync Library

Tags: python, linux, exchange-server, hotmail, activesync

Is anyone familiar with an Exchange ActiveSync library or open source client for python? I've done preliminary searching with little to no success. I've seen some examples for C#, but I figured I'd ask around here before my attempt to port anything over.

In case you're curious. This would be an extension of an already existing linux based IMAP / POP3 client. Moving to Windows / C# this late in the game isn't really an option.

Comment: i should also mention that activesync would be a great solution for being able to access gmail over http, for platforms such as appengine which don't allow sockets (and therefore, imap). incidentally, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Specifically, the first phase would include collecting email messages from all folders from Hotmail.

Comment: I'll note that as of December 2012, planning for GMail access via ActiveSync is a bad idea since Google has deprecated and will be discontinuing "consumer" ActiveSync.

Comment: Microsoft claims to hold patents on Exchange ActiveSync.  So if you add ActiveSync to your client, you might wish to warn your users that it is a patent-encumbered protocol.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 9:

```
apt-get install mercurial python-twisted
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/drspringfield/py-eas-client
cd py-eas-client
python setup.py install
python imap_to_eas_proxy.py --domain example.org --server mail.example.org --device_id myID.example.net
```

then connect via insecure IMAP to `localhost:3143` and log in as normal.  (For the Exchange server I was trying to connect to, this just threw `Activesync error Connection lost`, but it might work on other Exchange servers and/or when py-eas-client is improved.)

Comment: Dead link, so dead answer

Comment: @ThomasWard try this instead: `git clone https://github.com/ghiewa/py-eas-client` (found by searching Google for "py-eas-client" and looking for where it's currently hosted)