# Send command to exchange server via ActiveSync using Python

Tags: python, exchange-server, win32com, activesync

I want to fetch the settings information for an user. The needed command is documented here: [ActiveSync Command Reference Protocol Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202944(v=exchg.80).aspx)
I assume I have to use win32com.client.Dispatch("Something") to get an ActiveSync connection to my Exchange server which I can use to issue the mentioned 'Settings' command.

Seems like there is no library available: [Python Exchange ActiveSync Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547131/python-exchange-activesync-library)

Comment: You could try and utilize powershell from your python program, but this is not ideal. I too am interested in connecting to an EAS server from python, as a module of some sort.